# How to build .sid virtual raster catalog

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, mrsid, raster-catalog

I want to build raster catalog that would contain many .sid (MrSID) georeferenced rasters. I already successfully built such catalog with tiffs using gdalbuildvrt but when I try with .sid, every raster is its own band.
I presume problem is in gdal understanding MrSID compression, since importing individual images into QGIS works fine. 
How can I build catalog for use in QGIS with these images without converting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while found a way to build VRT. I used `Virtual Raster Builder` plugin that can also handle .sid files.